# What does the SOG part of this METAR mean?

Tags: metar, canada, meteorology

> CWKX 231700Z AUTO 12001KT M05/M07 RMK AO1 SOG 32 6023 SLP123 T10471068

Does anyone know what “SOG 32 6023” means?

Also why is that type of metar have a bunny icon in it instead of the M or the classic circle?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AviationStackExchange. SOG stands for Snow On the Ground. And, AO1 means that there is not an automated precipitation discriminator. I can not find any meaning for a “bunny icon”. Please include an image of the graphical METAR, please.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Could you tell us exactly which parts of the METAR you can’t read? It isn’t really clear if you’re asking about the whole thing or just some individual pieces.

Comment: Thank  for the answer, This part SOG 32 6023 i understand is snow on ground but those numbers what does mean? and the icon of the image

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I edited your question to make it a little more specific. You might like to ask about the icon in a separate question, we usually prefer one point per question on this site. The [tour] might be useful if you’re new to the site.

Comment: Thank  you for helping me and i will ask the icon in other question so do i deleted that part of the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RMK section:

AO1 = an observation
taken by equipment without a precipitation type discriminator (rain/snow)

SOG 32 = snow on ground, thickness 32 cm

6023 = beats me, I'll keep looking...

SLP176 = sea level pressure: what the current barometric pressure at measurement location would be at sea level, 176 stands for 1017.6 hPa (10 is omitted as persistent)

T10471068 =temperature and dewpoint in two four digit groups: first 0 or 1 for above or below zero degrees, then three digits for tenths of Celcius grades, so in the case above temperature is -4.7 deg C, dewpoint is -6.8 deg C

Comment: In the US, the procode for a US METAR, “6”,  marks the start of where the METAR denotes the amount of precipitation in the previous 3 or 6 hours. In the US, the procode “6” is followed by four digits that represents precipitation observed in .01 inches. Six hours is reported on the 00, 06, 12, & 18 UTC hours. Three hours is reported on the 03, 09, 15, & 21 UTC hours. This is spelled out in FAA AIM section 7-1-12. Since the METAR in question is from Canada, I would hazard a guess that the three digits following “6” are in centimeters.